# SQL Server, is this correct index usage?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, performance, indexing

I'm trying to get to grips with indexes.  Given the table:

```
Books
------
ID (PK)
Title
CategoryID (FK)
AuthorID (FK)
```

Where in my ASP.net pages, I have webpages that will fetch the books by author, or by category, would I create an index on `CategoryID Asc, AuthorID asc` if I wanted to improve retrieval times?

Have I correctly understood it?  If I use multiple columns as above, is that called a `clustered index` or is that something else?

Comment: *Clustered Index* is what the table is physically ordered by; an index consisting of more than one columns is called a **compound** index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create two indexes, one for the `CategoryID` and one for the `AuthorID`. Having both in the same index is not what you need if you look for one *or* the other; you'd need that if you were always querying for both at the same time (e.g. category and author).

A clustered index controls the physical order of the data. Usually, if you have an identity column, using it as clustered index (which the primary key by default is) is just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  In my SQL profiler I had a query that ran 17ms on CPU, I didn't change any data but went through my tables putting indexes on (in I think the correct way!) and then when I re run this query the profiler now says 0ms on the CPU.  Is this the sort of benefits adding indexes should be aiming toward?

Comment: @Tom Gullen Yes, adding indexes should improve read-performance. But they will create a small overhead in maintaining the index, so the write-performance will go down. However, in most web applications read-performance is a lot more important than write-performance.

Comment: @Tom Gullen No, a linked-list would require you to potentially scan the whole list each time. A tree is used, and a popular type of tree is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree which actually is a linked-list in the leaf nodes. This allows for fast range-queries.

Answer (score 3):

A *clustered* index means the data is stored in the table and on disk (etc.) in the order the index specifies. A consequence of this is, that only one clustered index can exist.

The index `CategoryID Asc, AuthorID asc` will make lookups on specific categories faster, and lookups on specific categories with specific authors would be ideal. But it is not ideal for author lookups alone because you will have to find authors for every category. In that case two separate indexes would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate index would depends on what the query does. If you have a query joining against both category and author, then you may have use for an index with both fields, otherwise you may have more use for two separate indexes.

A clustered index is an index that decides the storage order of the records in the table, and has nothing to do with the number of fields it contains. You should already have a clustered index on the primary key, so you can't create another clustered index for that table.